# why my text is not appearing above jsPdf Autotable?

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm using autotable in jsPDF to create index page,
my code looks likes this :

```
let page_3_main_title = "Index";
 pdf.setFontSize(12);
 pdf.setFontType("Times New Roman");
 pdf.text(page_3_main_title, 105, 20, "center");
var page_3_title = ['Sr No.', 'Particulars', 'Page No']
var page_3_body = [
  [1, "Location and location sketch"],
  [2, "Details of beds"],
  [3, "Seed details"],
  [4, "Pre-treatment of Seeds"],
  [5, "Details of Sowing"],
  [6, "Watering"],
  [7, "Plant/Seedlings Protection measure"],
  [8, "Observations"],
  [9, "Inspection Notes"],
  [10, "Cost Analysis"],
  [11, "Details of Disposal of Seedlings"],
  [12, "Photograph"],
];
    pdf.autoTable(page_3_title, page_3_body, { theme: "grid" });
```

I'm able to print the index in a table but the text "INDEX" above the table is not printing, what might be the reason?
[image]

Comment: you are over riding the `page_3_title` with an array , just use it like `const main_heading = "Index"` and then `pdf.autoTable(didDrawPage : main_heading,page_3_title, page_3_body, { theme: "grid" });`

Comment: Yeah, I actually did that and tried to print using  --  pdf.autoTable(page_3_title, page_3_body, {
      theme: "grid",
      didDrawPage: page_3_main_title,
    });

But no luck

Comment: try this if it works : `pdf.autoTable(didDrawPage: function () {
      pdf.setFontSize(18)
      pdf.text('Index')
    }, ........................`

Comment: This worked for me - pdf.autoTable(page_3_title, page_3_body, {startY: 40}).

                                                       40 is the vertical distance from the top.

Answer (score 0):

I think you had the same issue as I had.. you need to adjust the y axis coordinate of the starting point of your table. Add the option `startY: 75` to your autotable creation function and it will be set lower so you will see your text as it should be the case.

should look like:

```
*pdf.autoTable(page_3_title, page_3_body, startY: 75, { theme: "grid" });*
```

Comment: This worked for me - pdf.autoTable(page_3_title, page_3_body, {startY: 40}). 40 is the vertical distance from the top.